# Make Service listen to Hardware Keypress

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want a service that would be running in background and which would be listening to power button keypress; as soon as power button is pressed, i want service to do something.

correct me if im wrong..
i have read at some places that hardware keypress can be implemented by only activities using BroadcastReceiver.

and if above is true then i think should go for binding service to activity and calling service's method from activity when power button is pressed ..

how do i implement the above thing, appreciate good guidance! :)